# Angular Controller is not triggering

Tags: angularjs

My controller is not triggering. It should be stupid but I can't see why.

Here find my code structure.

Please help me find that basic error.

template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="attachmentsApp" ng-cloak="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>


  <script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
var source = [[${source}]];
var appContext = /*[[@{/}]]*/ '';
/*]]>*/
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div th:replace="include"></div>
<script th:src="@{/app/modules/attachments/scripts/attachmentsapp.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/app/modules/attachments/scripts/controllers/AttachmentsHomeCtrl.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/app/modules/attachments/scripts/services/AttachmentsHomeService.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App :

```
angular
  .module('attachmentsApp', ['ngRoute'
    ]).run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
        $rootScope.appContext = window.appContext;
        $rootScope.language = window.language;
        $rootScope.source = window.source;
    }])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: window.appContext + 'app/modules/attachments/views/home.html', controller: "AttachmentsHomeCtrl" })
    });
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('attachmentsApp').controller('AttachmentsHomeCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope','AttachmentsHomeService','$window', 
                                      function ($scope,$rootScope,AttachmentsHomeService,$window) {
    console.log($rootScope.source);
    debugger;
}]);
```

Service :

```
'use strict';
angular.module('attachmentsApp').service('AttachmentsService', [ '$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope){
    this.getForm = function(type) {
        debugger;
    }
    return this;
}]);
```

Many thanks

Comment: Do you have any console error ?

Comment: Nothing in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the Service name.

AttachmentsHomeService as registering it in Controller
AttachmentsService in service definition

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting some change in your HTML:

1) **Define and load files before their use**: ng-app was being used before `attachmentsapp.js` file is loaded in DOM

2) **Order of usage**: service file was loaded after its usage in controller

It should be look like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>


      <script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var source = [[${source}]];
    var appContext = /*[[@{/}]]*/ '';
    /*]]>*/
    </script>
    <script th:src="@{/app/modules/attachments/scripts/attachmentsapp.js}"></script>

<script th:src="@{/app/modules/attachments/scripts/services/AttachmentsHomeService.js}"></script>

<script th:src="@{/app/modules/attachments/scripts/controllers/AttachmentsHomeCtrl.js}"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="attachmentsApp" ng-cloak="">

    <div th:replace="include"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Not 100% sure, but it should be working. Do a try !!

Moreover, keep an eye on console.